# Strange preamble for a thesis or this is normal?

Tags: macros, templates, best-practices

I have a somewhat strange template that I should use for submit my dissertation for the speciality. I put the code as a minimal working example for you to see:

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mwe} % added for me

\makeatletter

% language
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

% tables
\usepackage{booktabs}

% characters
\usepackage{textcomp}

% rotate tables
\usepackage{rotating}


% bibliography will appear in the table of contents
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%margins
\usepackage{vmargin}

\setmarginsrb           { 4.0cm}  % left margin
                        { 4.0cm}  % top margcm
                        { 2.0cm}  % right margcm
                        { 3.0cm}  % bottom margcm
                        {  10pt}  % head height
                        {0.25cm}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.5cm}  % foot sep

% insertion url's footnotes.
\usepackage{url}

% Packages from the AMS:
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


% Theorems
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposición}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definición}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Observación}

% Shortcuts.
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}


\newcommand{\portada}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

{\large \bf TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN }
\vfill
%{\large\bf PRESENTADO POR \par}
{\large\bf NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO }\\
{\large\bf Código: 00000000001 }
\vfill
{\large\bf UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL  \par}
{\large\bf FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA \par}
{\large\bf ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ... \par}
{\large\bf D.C.\par}
{\large\bf NOVIEMBRE 2014 \par}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\contraportada}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\large \bf TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN }
\vfill       
%             {\large\bf PRESENTADO POR \par}
{\large\bf NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO } \\
{\large\bf Código: 00000000001 }
\vfill
{\large\bf Proyecto de grado \par}
\vfill
{\large\bf Director: Nombre Director \par}
\vfill
{\large\bf UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL  \par}
{\large\bf FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA \par}
{\large\bf ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ... \par}
{\large\bf D.C.\par}
{\large\bf NOVIEMBRE 2014 \par}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}

\makeatother

%\usepackage{babel}
\deactivatetilden

\hyphenation{auto-re-gu-la-do}

\begin{document}
\portada
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

My first doubt is about the use of `\makeatletter` and `\maketatother`. As I understand this commands are useful for add redefinitions in the code or small changes for the standard values of the class, but here there is a lot of code. And is also redundant with some packages, but that's fine?

What about the page dimensions, is this better to do instead of use geometry?

Why build the title page in that way, is the best way to do it?

I have not much experience with LaTeX, but for the little code I've seen so far, this is weird. My doubts are around two issues: one on best practice, I see and feel that this code is not the best solution, and on the other hand, in terms of efficiency. I guess although computers today have many resources, still a good idea to optimize your code in LaTeX, in that sense, it is optimized?

What advice can you give me on this? How could improve this template?

Comment: It is not that weird. It is not very good. Just being not very good is, unfortunately, not that weird. You are right that the `\makeatletter` stuff isn't needed. The issue isn't the amount of code but this is only needed if the code includes `@` as a letter and this doesn't. It uses commands which have been deprecated for a couple of decades. And, no, that is ***not*** a better way to set the margins than using `geometry`. `geometry` would definitely be better. Can you change it?

Comment: one thing that strikes me as odd is the presence of `\usepackage{amsthm}`, but no `\usepackage{amsmath}`.  if there are theorems, there is bound to be a lot of mathematical content, and basic latex doesn't offer very much flexibility in that department (and what it does offer, namely `eqnarray` is decidedly inferior in appearance).

Comment: You include `textcomp` twice...

Comment: @cfr I want to change it, to make it more efficient in some way, that's why I asked, thanks for the remarks.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I thought the same when I saw that mess.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Me not, in the University gave me that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

OK so far except that theses usually have chapters so `book` or `report` might be preferable.

```
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Better to use `parskip`:

```
\usepackage{parskip}% but do you really want no indentation in a thesis?
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}% if desired
```

...

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mwe} % added for me
```

OK, I think.

```
\makeatletter
```

Not needed.

```
% language
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

Doesn't need the option - it is in the document class options already.

```
% tables
\usepackage{booktabs}

% characters
\usepackage{textcomp}

% rotate tables
\usepackage{rotating}


% bibliography will appear in the table of contents
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%margins
\usepackage{vmargin}

\setmarginsrb           { 4.0cm}  % left margin
                        { 4.0cm}  % top margcm
                        { 2.0cm}  % right margcm
                        { 3.0cm}  % bottom margcm
                        {  10pt}  % head height
                        {0.25cm}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.5cm}  % foot sep
```

Not good at all. Much better to use `geometry` if you are allowed to.

```
% insertion url's footnotes.
\usepackage{url}

% Packages from the AMS:
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}


% Theorems
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposición}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definición}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Observación}

% Shortcuts.
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}
```

As egreg mentions in the comments, it would be much better to use `\newcommand*{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}` etc. here since this will include additional checks. (For example, it will not allow you to unwittingly overwrite an existing command.)

```
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
```

Not sure about these. Just not really my area.

```
\newcommand{\portada}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

{\large \bf TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN }
```

Bad. `\bf` is deprecated 20 years ago. Use `\textbf{}` or `\bfseries` instead. When you use a size switch (e.g. `\large`) you usually should end the paragraph within the scope of the command to get the line spacing right. Since there is a `\vfill` after it, this might not make much difference but a `\par` would not hurt.

```
\vfill
%{\large\bf PRESENTADO POR \par}
{\large\bf NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO }\\
{\large\bf Código: 00000000001 }
\vfill
{\large\bf UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL  \par}
{\large\bf FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA \par}
{\large\bf ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ... \par}
{\large\bf D.C.\par}
{\large\bf NOVIEMBRE 2014 \par}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\contraportada}{
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
{\large \bf TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN }
\vfill       
%             {\large\bf PRESENTADO POR \par}
{\large\bf NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO } \\
{\large\bf Código: 00000000001 }
\vfill
{\large\bf Proyecto de grado \par}
\vfill
{\large\bf Director: Nombre Director \par}
\vfill
{\large\bf UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL  \par}
{\large\bf FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA \par}
{\large\bf ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ... \par}
{\large\bf D.C.\par}
{\large\bf NOVIEMBRE 2014 \par}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
}
```

There are more elegant approaches but this is not bad, if the font commands etc. are corrected as explained above. Titlepages for these things are always a bit of a one-off since they need to be formatted according to all kinds of weird institutional guidelines. They usually involve manually setting things up in some way or other. If it weren't here, it would be in the class or package file. (That might be more sensible in terms of clutter but the code would be the same.)

```
\makeatother
```

Not needed.

```
%\usepackage{babel}
```

Again?

```
\deactivatetilden
```

No idea.

```
\hyphenation{auto-re-gu-la-do}

\begin{document}
\portada
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

## Putting it together

You probably want something like the following. I tried to emulate the margin settings using `geometry` but, in the end, I think it will be easier to work from the dimensions they want rather than trying to figure out what they are hoping `vmargin` will do. So I suggest getting the values and then using `\geometry{}` with the `verbose` option (and maybe `showframe`) to figure out the right configuration.

```
\documentclass[11pt,spanish,a4paper,oneside]{book}% or report
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
% characters
\usepackage{textcomp}
% insertion url's footnotes.
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{mwe} % added for me

% language
\usepackage{babel}

% tables
\usepackage{booktabs}

% rotate tables
\usepackage{rotating}

% bibliography will appear in the table of contents
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%margins
\usepackage{geometry}% find out the desired page dimensions and work from those to emulate the intended effect of vmargin (I think this will be easier than trying to base it on vmargin's configuration)

% Packages from the AMS:
\usepackage{mathtools}% loads amsmath plus enhancements and fixes
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% Theorems
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposición}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definición}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Observación}

% Shortcuts.
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*\RR{\mathbb{R}}% improved checking when defining new commands (better than \def)
\newcommand*\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}

\newcommand{\portada}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}% I would tend to use \centering but that will change the vertical spacing here so best go with this
      \large\bfseries% \bf is loooonnnng deprecated; no need to keep switching size and weight since all the switches are identical
      TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN
      \vfill
      %PRESENTADO POR \par
      NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO\\
      Código: 00000000001
      \vfill
      UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL\par
      FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA\par
      ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ...\par
      D.C.\par
      NOVIEMBRE 2014\par
    \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}}

\newcommand{\contraportada}{
  \begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
      \large\bfseries
      TÍTULO DE LA DISERTACIÓN
      \vfill
      %PRESENTADO POR \par
      NOMBRE DEL ALUMNO\\
      Código: 00000000001
      \vfill
      Proyecto de grado\par
      \vfill
      Director: Nombre Director\par
      \vfill
      UNIVERSIDAD DISTRITAL\par
      FACULTAD DE INGENIERÍA\par
      ESPECIALIZACIÓN EN ...\par
      D.C.\par
      NOVIEMBRE 2014\par
    \end{center}
  \end{titlepage}}

\deactivatetilden

\hyphenation{auto-re-gu-la-do}

\begin{document}
  \portada
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought also about use book instead of article. How to use parskip? `textcomp, url, graphicx, setspace, \onehalfspacing` and `amssymb` are not needed? I think also is better to use geometry. About the _math_ code is something generic if we need it, not very useful for me. I'ma gree with the coment of the titlepage but I don't understood that about `\vfill`. I also don't understad what is `\deactivatetilden`. And well that definition of class has few things repeated.

Comment: @IraultzaBelaustegigoitia Sorry, no. I just meant that `\makeletter` wasn't needed. I'll edit to clarify. I imagine the tilde thing has to do with `babel` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @egreg I already say 'Bad. \bf is deprecated 20 years ago. Use \textbf{} or \bfseries instead.' What exactly do you want me to add? [I've added the `\def` bit but suggested `\newcommand*`.]